# tensorflow.estimator error: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I can't seem to find the issue in the code that causes the error. I would appreciate it if you could help. Thanks in advance! The error generated from the code below is

**TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable**

```
n_batches = 1
est = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(feature_columns,
                                          n_batches_per_layer=n_batches)

est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)

result = est.evaluate(eval_input_fn.())
clear_output()
print(pd.Series(result))
```

Comment: Are you sure of that `eval_input_fn>>>.<<<()`?

Comment: I got the same error after the .() was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to: `result = est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)`

The `()`brackets after the `eval_input_fn` is not required, just like the way `train_input_fn` is passed to `train()`

TF documentation defines the `input_fn` as

> A function that constructs the input data for evaluation.